# Does Objective-C support C# style attributes?

Tags: objective-c

Does Objective-C support marking properties/methods with attributes? like so:

```
#MyAttribute //sudo example
@porperty (nonatomic, retain) NSString * myString;
```

I would then like to "reflect" over the class and determine what attribute is attached to the property "myString".

Is something like this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no attributes in Objective-C.  You do get a form of reflection, you can test an instance to see if it exists in the instance, but that is all you get.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for some form of class metadata but it looks like I will have to make another plan.