# Objective-C equivalent to C# Attributes?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Objective-C support C# style attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657259/does-objective-c-support-c-sharp-style-attributes)

In C# you can associate declarative information to code (types, methods, properties etc.) by using "Attributes" like this:

```
class Account {
  [IsTested] // <---- Attribute to the method
  public void AddOrder(Order orderToAdd) {
     orders.Add(orderToAdd);
  }
}
```

Is there anything similar in Objective-c? Maybe something like:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    NSString *name;
}
[IsTested]
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
```

You would then be able to use reflection to go over your properties and take different actions based on wich "attributes" were assigned to them.

Comment: oups, yes... What is the appropriate thing to do? Remove my post?

Comment: I don't know of anything, but there may be some trick you can play with Objective-C's "runtime" API.  You can associate objects with other objects by key, however, so you could possibly use a naming convention to associate attributes with individual functions.  But this is for objects, not classes, so you might have to create a "token" instance to hold these attributes.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: Classes are also objects in ObjC --- though a *property* is not.

Comment: Classes are not **Objective-C** objects.

Comment: @Cotten: Up to you. You can vote to close, I think. Then this question will link to the other.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: Yes, they certainly are. See http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html, http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html, and the source: http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.3/runtime/objc-class.m

Comment: Well, that's news to me.  I never looked at it closely, but assumed that they aren't.  I'll have to play with that a bit.